# Font on React app not found when deployed on azure web app

Tags: reactjs, fonts, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I've been trying since the morning to deploy my simple react app on azure, everything is loaded perfectly except the FONTS !
here's what i get in the console

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
 CircularStd-Bold.5c4514a8399ec0064b9b.otf
```

when i access the link of the font i get a page with the following error

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

i read thousands of articles i did add my web.config file to the public folder, with the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG PLEASE?

Comment: Are you able to see the web.config in the KUDU console,It has to be in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's an the wwwroot folder after adding the webconfig file and the fonts present in the static file

[image]